# What Java features do you lose when using -source or -target directives for previous versions?

Tags: java, javac

So I know that javac can take a `-source` flag which allows you to specify which Java version it should use to compile the source code:

- If you use source 1.7 then you lose lambdas, type annotations, and default methods in interfaces from 1.8.
- If you use source 1.6 then you lose <>, try-with-resources, and multicatch from 1.7.
- If you use source 1.5 then you lose `@Override` in interfaces.
- If you use source 1.4 then you lose generics, autoboxing, for/in, varargs, and enums.
- If you use source 1.3 then you lose assertions.

But it also takes a `-target` flag which allows you to generate bytecode targeting a specific JVM version. I'm interested in seeing a list like the one above of features which were added in each version so that I can make an intelligent decision about how far back I want to `-target`. For example, is there some version behind which it's not recommended I target, for performance reasons or even because some language features break?

Comment: There is no good reason to target older versions, except for compatibility. You should use the most recent version that you can...

Comment: Don't you already have this information under the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) ? Under `-target version` it tells you what target corresponds to a source which can help you determine what features you miss out on.

Comment: There are actually 3 different variables -- the compiler level, the level that the JVM can handle, and the runtime library level (which is only loosely tied to the JVM level).  I recall looking for a list of the JVM level limitations maybe 7-8 years back and not finding anything, though.  It's kind of a secret kept by the javac guys, I think.